# PostgreSQL/PgAdmin 4 date type declaration, to allow entering of date as just M/YYYY

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, types, format

Can a date type variable such as 'DateStarted' be declared in such a way as to allow the user to enter just '9/2002' as an entry? If, I would appreciate being shown the syntax for it.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-formatting.html to_date should work with just 'M/YYYY'.

Comment: So my best bet, is to store the '9/2002' as a string, then when I want to perform related queries involving 'date' types, convert 9/2002 to a date data type. What about the 'day' value, which as we see, is not entered into '9/2002'?